# Import QIF file and enter record in database using php

Tags: php, qif

I have .qif file and i import this file and enter record in database using PHP

How i get data from qif file and make simple array for insert data in to database.

sample array in below

```
Array
    (
        [type] => ASSETS
        [full_name] => Assets
        [name] => Assets
        [description] => Assets
        [notes] => 
    )
```

I also insert transaction of account.

sample array is below

```
Array
    (
        [DATE] => 10/09/2014
        [AMOUNT] => 61.5
        [SERIAL] => 
        [DESCRIPTION] => INTERNET FUNDS XFER
        [TRANCODE] => Deposit
    )
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: you can try to convert qif to csv format refer here[https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/need-a-qif-to-csv-xls-converter-is-there-any.1027728/] after that you can easily import into database ....

Comment: this qif to csv convert is possible in to php

Comment: i'm not sure about that but you can convert your file qif to csv using converters online after that import easily into db..you can refer here(https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/need-a-qif-to-csv-xls-converter-is-there-any.1027728/) and here(https://www.downloadcloud.com/qif-to-csv-converter.html)

Comment: can you give me actual and popular name of tool which convert qif to csv?

Comment: please see this https://github.com/fbrnc/qif2csv/blob/master/qif2csv.php
i think this not perfect